# using jquery when passing arguments to function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a link which triggers js function. To the link I have attached data-attribute on html which I want to pass to the function.

```
$(".trigger").awesomeFunction({
  oneArgument: "secretSauce",
  secondArgument: $(this).data("address")
});
```

Now that second argument ends up null instead of the data-address attribute. Is it because $(this) is not in right scope inside the function arguments list and if so how could I refer to the originating link?

Comment: Without showing the code of your `awesomeFunction`, nothing can be said.

Comment: awesomeFunction is [here](https://github.com/harryhorn/jquery-popover/blob/master/jquery.popover.js) . The argument I'm trying to pass as a secondArgument on the above example is not on the original functions code, I've added that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure how your `awesomeFunction` is defined, but this seems to do the trick.

```
$.fn.awesomeFunction = function(obj){
    console.log(obj.sauceType, this.data(obj.dataArg))
    // returns 'secretSauce 123 Anystreet Dr.'
}
var div = $('#theDiv')
div.awesomeFunction({
    sauceType : 'secretSauce',
    dataArg : 'address'
})
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/phix/qEfuS/1/)

Comment: Yup, ended up passing just the data-attribute name and doing the value lookup on the plugin side.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".trigger").click(function() { 
    var self = $(this);
    self.awesomeFunction({ 
        oneArgument: "secretSauce",
        secondArgument: self.data("address")
    });
});
```

Comment: As long as you've got `self` defined, why not say `self.awesomeFunction({...})`?

Comment: While this works on passing the argument, it breaks the functionality of the function/plugin I'm referring here which is [https://github.com/harryhorn/jquery-popover/blob/master/jquery.popover.js](https://github.com/harryhorn/jquery-popover/blob/master/jquery.popover.js)

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".trigger").each(function() { 
    var self = $(this);
    self.awesomeFunction({ 
        oneArgument: "secretSauce",
        secondArgument: self.data("address")
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Given your code sample, anything could happen, `this` is not defined in the scope of `.trigger`, you're "one layer out" so to speak.

[See this fiddle for example](http://jsfiddle.net/8YrKD/)

Comment: Tried this, but the dataArg still ends up null.

Comment: Here you can see the calling of the function and beginning of the function called [http://pastie.org/3262169](http://pastie.org/3262169)

Comment: In the case you supplied `this` be the `window` object